# HttpResponse is not getting the JSON returned by the server

Tags: android, python, json, httpresponse

I have a RESTful API server using Flask, it treats JSON requests, when I use curl to execute the POST method I get the answer I want.

```
~$curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":"3","aircraft":"PRVLL","origin":"SBME","destination":"SBFS","departure":"11:00","route":"MAPRO"}' http://radiant-harbor-4344.herokuapp.com/dublinAirport/
HTTP/1.1 201 CREATED
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 12 Apr 2014 20:11:18 GMT
Server: gunicorn/18.0
Content-Length: 166
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "flightPlan": {
  "aircraft": "PRVLL", 
  "departure": "11:00", 
  "destination": "SBFS", 
  "id": "3", 
  "origin": "SBME", 
  "route": "MAPRO"
}
```

But when I try to use the HttpResponse class to perform the POST I get all the content from the URL. Like if I was making a GET request to the [URL](http://radiant-harbor-4344.herokuapp.com/dublinAirport/), instead of getting the response from the JSON message.

Here my Java code, I've tried using EntityUtils also, but I get the same result.

```
public JSONObject postJSONToUrl(String url,String jsonMsg)
{
    try 
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonMsg));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        //String jsonResponse = new String();
        //jsonResponse = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        //Log.i("STRING_CONVERTED", jsonResponse);
        Log.i("STRING_CONVERTED", response);
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);  //jsonResponse

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
    }
    return jsonObj;
}
```

Here is my Python code, server-side:
Basically it treats the request and returns a JSON message.

```
@app.route('/<airportName>/', methods = ['POST'])
def create_plans(airportName):
    if not request.json: #handle errors
        abort(400)
    expectedAirport = searchAirport(airportList, airportName);
    #here two lines of code just to get the {} off of the new airports, because now will be some content there
    if expectedAirport[0]=={}:
      expectedAirport.remove({})
    #
    flightPlan = {
        #'id': len(expectedAirport) + 1,             //Sincronize part
        'id': request.json['id'],
        'aircraft': request.json['aircraft'],
        'origin': request.json['origin'],
        'destination': request.json['destination'],
        'departure': request.json.get('departure'),
        'route': request.json.get('route')
    }
    expectedAirport.append(flightPlan)
    return jsonify( { 'flightPlan': flightPlan } ), 201
```

The answer for this question probably is related to how HttpResponse works or how the DefaultHttpClient.execute() works, because the CURL is returning exactly what I want and this method isn't.

Comment: So I started to think and I got the conclusion that the DefaultHttpClient class was actually doing a GET request after the POST, instead of getting the answer returned by the server.
To test it I changed the URL of the request, and guess what??
It got the answer that was in the GET method for the new URL.

So I got the conclusion that the DefaultHttpClient class is actually executing two methods. It does the POST, and after that is does a GET to the same URL, and consider it as the answer, instead of getting the results that are returned from the server (as CURL does).

Comment: I found the problem.
The thing was how backslash after the URL works in Flask.
    @app.route('/<airportName>/', methods = ['POST'])
As I was making a request that didn't end with backslash, flask was redirecting me, the new page had another content different from my return.
And that was the problem. Now it's fixed.